# A vector $\mathbf{x}\in X$ has coordinates $\mathbf{x}_\mathcal{B}= \langle2,-7,-10\rangle$. What is $\mathbf{x}_\mathcal{G}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis, transition-matrix

(i'd really appreciate if someone fixed the notation, i have no clue how to do it. thanks)

[image]

You are given this information at the start of the question:
[image]

Really stuck on this, i have no clue what to do so i cant really give you any additional information. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). E.g., `\mathbf{x}_\mathcal{B}=\pmatrix{2\\-7\\-10}`

Comment: Cheers! @ChaseRyanTaylor

Answer (score 0):

Just apply $P_{B\to G}$ to $x_B$: $x_G
=P_{B\to G}(x_B)
=\begin{pmatrix}1\cdot2+2\cdot(-7)+(-1)\cdot(-10)\\(-2)\cdot2+1\cdot(-7)+0\cdot(-10)\\ 0\cdot2+1\cdot(-7)+1\cdot(-10)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2\\-11\\-17\end{pmatrix}$